# Luigi overwrite to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, luigi

I have a routine task to upload and share a dump on S3 bucket. While the code below works, for some reason it does not want to overwrite file.

From the docs, I need to 
1) define solution for two parallel executions:
    `path = luigi.Parameter(default=glob(DATA_DIR)[-2], batch_method=max)`

2) add `resources = {'overwrite_resource': 1}`

While it works for the local files - it does not for the S3.

```
class report_to_S3(luigi.Task):
    client = S3Client()
    path = luigi.Parameter(default=glob(DATA_DIR)[-2], batch_method=max)
    local_dump_path = '../../../data/local_db_dump.csv'
    resources = {'overwrite_resource': 1}

    def requires(self):
        return upload_tweets(path=self.path)

    def output(self):
        self.s3_path = "s3://qclm-nyc-ct/dump/dump.csv"
        return S3Target(self.s3_path, client=self.client)

    def run(self):
        c = sqa.create_engine('postgresql:///qc_soc_media')
        df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT id, user_id, timestamp, lat, lon, ct FROM tweets WHERE ct IS NOT NULL', c)
        N = len(df)
        df.to_csv(self.local_dump_path, index=None)
        self.client.put(self.local_dump_path, self.output().path,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/csv'})
        send_S3_report(N)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run(local_scheduler=True, main_task_cls=report_to_S3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target specified in the output() method already exists, the run() method will not execute. You may want to work the timestamp into the filename, or create another sentinel/flag that indicates the work is done.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I don't want that. Original Luigi allows to overwrite this behavior using resources = {'overwrite_resource': 1} for the local targets, but it seems it does not work for the S3 bucket (a bug?)

Comment: 'overwrite_resource' is just a technique for creating a resource that prevents multiple tasks from running at the same time- you could use any string there. (typically resources are limits on things like concurrent API connections, etc). If you don't want to work the timestamp into the filename, just create some other indicator to use in the output() method. The task will not run if the output already exists.

Comment: Thanks, I made a log file as a target, it seems to work.

Comment: cool. I should also note that if you don't want to have any output target that is unique to your task run with params, you can write a custom complete() method for the task. (in case existence of your log file is not an atomic indicator of task success)

Comment: Thanks. In the end, It appeared to be a little bit more complex than I anticipated: I created an additional LocalTarget for the logfile as a class parameter, and then overwrote `complete` with checking if this localTarget exists. 

The reason for this workaround is that I still need the `output()` to point other tasks to the correct data path (Duh)